# Scraped text is connected, how can I separate?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, node-horseman

I am scraping plain text from websites but I can't seem to separate the text.

Here is what I mean...

```
var Horseman = require("node-horseman");
var horseman = new Horseman();

horseman
  .open('http://nickoskitchen.com/')
  .text('.rc-headline')
  .then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
    horseman.close();
  });
```

The result from running this script ...

```
admin:~/workspace $ node test4.js
Recipes Inspired By New York City Street Foods10 More Unbelievable Red Velvet Desserts10 Twists On The Deviled EggElevate These 10 Dishes With Earthy Artichoke
```

See? It's being retrieved as one string but when I .count() I end up getting 4 results.

If someone could please help me with this issue I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 2):

The `text()` method just gets the textual content of the matched selector, so any list style (or any html element/style used to separate the values) you see on the page is lost, and you are left with the garbled text.

There is an npm package you may want to look at if what you want to do is scrape the site for some content. It's called [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) (jQuery for the server). Add it to your code like this

```
var Horseman = require("node-horseman");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var horseman = new Horseman();

horseman
  .open('http://nickoskitchen.com/')
  .html()
  .then(function(html){
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      var headlines = $('.rc-headline');
      headlines.each(function(){
          console.log($(this).text());
      });
      horseman.close();
  });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are a life saver, Kennasoft. How much do you charge per hour for consultation? I would be very interested in your help. You are an outstanding developer from looking at your profile.

Comment: Thanks for the compliments, but I'm as ordinary as they get. I just happened to have come across cheerio before you. As per charging, Stackoverflow exists exactly for that reason: so we don't have to pay to have our problems solved. Accept & Upvote the answer, & I'll be happy with that. Thanks!